# Can't drop down to virtual console. All I see are the system login/boot messages (like a bootup screen) - can't type anthing

Tags: linux, sddm, virtual-consoles

Ctrl+Alt+F1 workedgave me access to the console before, now it shows me the boot up and login process messages ("started CUPS, network manager etc.)

The funny thing is my graphical session works but I can't drop down to the console. If anything, it should be the other way around lol, since the latter is used to rescue the former in case of emergencies (well, that's Linux for you).

Does anyone know what's causing this nonsense and how to get the console back?process

Comment: The `login:` prompt has probably scrolled off the screen due to the flood of bootup messages.  Hit enter on the console.  You should see the login: prompt again.

Comment: Heh, I tried that already. Doesn't do anything. I see a blinking cursor after the last message so it's not off screen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to press ctrl+alt+f6 to go to virtual console, although I never had to do this before.